# Como usar o JobScheduler?

Tags: java, android

Eu tou com um projeto para fazer minha activity  acordar a cada 12 horas e nao consegui achar  código que de certo sobre o JobScheduler , alguém pode me ajudar com o código ?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android